# Lotusscript - Printing a Notes-Document with NotesUIDocument.Print does not work as documented

Tags: printing, lotusscript

I want to print Notes-documents directly to an pdf-printer. The documents are selected in a view. I do not want to open the printer dialog form.

Using the "NotesUIView.Print"- method works in principle, however, the generated pdf-documents sometimes look not exactly like the Notes-documents (especially regarding tables).

Therefore I tried to use the "NotesUIDocument.Print" - method:

```
Option Public
Option Explicit

Const pdfAppName = "PDF-XChange Standard"

Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim curDoc As NotesDocument
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
...
Set dc  = curDB.UnprocessedDocuments
...
Set curdoc = dc.GetFirstDocument
Call workspace.EditDocument(False,curDoc)
Set uidoc = workspace.Currentdocument
Call uidoc.Print(1,0,0,False,pdfAppName)
...
```

Dispite the first parameter in "uidoc.print" is set to "1" the printer dialog form opens. In the printer dialog form the printer "PDF-XChange Standard" is selected correctly. Selecting the "OK"-Button prints the document correctly.

Many thanks in advance for hints.

Comment: If the printer name does not match exactly, the print dialog will appear.  The printer may have already been selected from a previous print.

Comment: You are right regarding the selection from a previous print. When I change the standard printer to another printer and run the script, the printer dialog form opens with the name of the standard printer. So the name of the printer declared in Const pdfName is not selected.

Comment: However, when I use the "NotesUIView.Print"- method with exactly the same pdf-printer name, declared in "Const pdfAppName", everything runs smoothly. The printer dialog form does not show up and the pdf-document is generated.